# Jinja2 template from Flask is failing to render CONTINUE statement

Tags: templates, flask, jinja2, continue

I am trying a simple `continue` inside a `for-loop` in Flask with jinja2

```
{% for num in range(0,10) %}
  {% if num%2 == 0 %}
    {% print num %}
  {% else %}
    {% continue %}
  {% endif %}
```

and i get this error

`TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'continue'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.`

Here is the jinja2 documentation that i followed... http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#loop-controls

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add the loop controls extension for Jinja 2 to your app:

```
app.jinja_env.add_extension('jinja2.ext.loopcontrols')
```